# Show $f\left( x\right) =x^{2}$ is strictly monotone on $\left[ 0,1\right]$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Note that $f$ is said to be motonote (respectively, strictly monotone) on $E$ if and only if $f$ is either decreasing or increasing (respectively, either sitrictly decreasing or strictly increasing) on $E$.

How can I show this question? Can you help?

Comment: Hint: $f(a)-f(b)=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: you want to show that $(x+c)^2\ge x^2$ for $x,c>0$ and $x+c\in[0,1]$

Comment: @OlivierOloa can you give a more hint?

Comment: @Masacroso Actually, we need to show that this is either decreasing or increasing,right?

Comment: @OlivierOloa by the mean value, there is a $c$ in $(a,b)$ sucht that $f'(c)=\dfrac {f\left( b\right) -f\left( a\right) } {b-a}=a+b$, so, what should I do now?

Comment: @Kahler I think you can use $ a>b \implies f(a)>f(b)$ to show $f$ is strictly increasing, then use $a>b>0$ and consider the sign $f(a)-f(b)=(a-b)(a+b)$. hope it helps.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Can I take $a=0$ and $b=1$, thus, $f(0)<f(1)$ then $f$ is increasing. Hence, are we done?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is strictly positive on $(0,1)$, but by more elementary means, consider $x \geq0, a > 0$:

$$(x+a)^2 > x^2 \iff x^2 + 2ax + a^2 > x^2 \iff a(2x+a) > 0$$

and the last inequality is true since both $a$ and $2x+a$ are positive.